# How to profit your Omaha knowledges against Holdem comming players in short-handed games

Tags: poker-strategy, omaha

I started to play some Holdem but move to Omaha soon around ten years ago. I have played more than 250000 Omaha short handed 6-max hands while only some Holdem tournaments.

I now know I have been gambling for ten years only not loosing a lot because I play in low tables.

I read Jeff Hwang's "Pot-Limit Omaha Poker: The Big Play Strategy" and started to select my hands. I know I am doing this better than many Holdem preflop loose players.

I buyed the series of books "Advanced Pot-Limit Omaha" and I am reading the second one. I started to consider position and realized the best is to play with position head-ups with speculative hands, while trying to make the pot multiway in potential nut cards as 789T.

After all I have played more than 250000 hands, I am not completely newbie, so I have started to win in 0,05-0,10€ games (I guess just because I select better the games to play/raise than my oponnents).

I am earning some hundreds/month. I have a job, but I will be nice I can earn my life playing a game I love, not needing to wake-up early to do my boring job at 7am.

What I am asking is tips to profit my knowledge to beat Holdem coming players even the games are 6-max (short-handed).

What are the common mistakes they make?

Comment: Won't add this as an answer, but I think the biggest mistakes I've seen NLH players make in PLO are not understanding how pot works, not understanding you don't need to bet pot all the time, really shitty hand selection (i.e. happy with things like JJ27 rainbow. Often they just see the Js and think that's fine), not understanding the power of draws, overvaluing strong NLH hands, undervaluing strong drawing PLO hands. Also they have a complete misunderstanding of what they should be reaching to river with. I've seen a lot reach river with single pair hands on wet boards. Also MUST use 2 cards!

Comment: @Grinch91 Thanks, that looks like the start of an answer if you want to say more things. Other mistake Jeff Hwang mentions in the books I am reading is to defend the blinds and sometimes raise out of position with speculative hands.

Comment: If nothing has been provided in by Wednesday I'll put it as an answer. Will be freer to put something by then.